# Changing indices within a Haskell tree

Tags: haskell, functor, traversable, foldable

(Sorry for the long context description, but I couldn't find a simpler way to explain my problem) Consider the following types:

```
import Data.Array

data UnitDir = Xp | Xm | Yp | Ym | Zp | Zm
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded, Ix)

type Neighborhood a = Array UnitDir (Tree a)

data Tree a = Empty | Leaf a | Internal a (Neighborhood a)
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Clearly, `Tree` can be defined as an instance of `Functor` as follows:

```
instance Functor Tree where
    fmap _ Empty           = Empty
    fmap f (Leaf x)        = Leaf (f x)
    fmap f (Internal x ts) = Internal (f x) $ fmap (fmap f) ts
```

I would like to define a function that traverses an instance of `Tree` by permuting the indices of the `Array UnitDir (Tree a)` (so it's a permutation on the 6 possible values of `UnitDir`).

A possible implementation would be this one:

```
type Permutation = Array UnitDir UnitDir

applyPermutation :: Permutation -> Tree a -> Tree a
applyPermutation _ Empty = Empty
applyPermutation _ (Leaf x) = Leaf x
applyPermutation f (Internal x ts) = Internal x (applyPermutation' ts)
    where applyPermutation' ts = ixmap (Xp, Zm) (f !) (applyPermutation f <$> ts)
```

My question is the following: Is there a natural Haskell construction to "traverse" the tree while reindexing the children?

`Functor` does not work, since I use it to change the content of the tree, not its indexing scheme. It seems I would need two instances of `Functor`, one to change the content and the other to change the array indices.

I thought that `Traversable` would be the right choice, but none of the signatures of the provided functions matches that of `applyPermutation`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A traversal would be a function to relabel the leaves, i.e., just a monadic generalization of functors.  If you meant to apply the permutation recursively at every level, that would be a catamorphism (a fold, but in a different sense from `Foldable`). But as it currently is, I don't see an interesting generalization.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out catamorphisms. This is exactly what I need!

Comment: There were a few errors in `applyPermutation` -- it looked like you might have accidentally pasted an older version of your function. I took the liberty of editing them away. Feel free to edit it further if I guessed what you meant wrongly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `Functor` does not work, since I use it to change the content of the tree, not its indexing scheme. It seems I would need two instances of `Functor`, one to change the content and the other to change the array indices.

Your intuition here is spot on: a functor that acted on the `Neighborhood a` field would do what you need, and it is correct to call such a thing "functor". Here is one possible refactoring of `applyPermutation`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

-- I prefer case syntax for this sort of definition; with it, there is less stuff
-- that needs to be repeated. LambdaCase is the icing on the cake: it frees me
-- me from naming the Tree a argument -- without it I would be forced to write
-- mapOverNeighborhoods f t = case t of {- etc. -}
mapOverNeighborhoods :: (Neighborhood a -> Neighborhood a) -> Tree a -> Tree a
mapOverNeighborhoods f = \case 
    Empty -> Empty
    Leaf x -> Leaf x
    Internal x ts -> Internal x (f (mapOverNeighborhoods f <$> ts))

applyPermutation :: Permutation -> Tree a -> Tree a
applyPermutation perm = mapOverNeighborhoods applyPermutation'
    where applyPermutation' = ixmap (Xp, Zm) (perm !)
```

(You might prefer to go even further and use a mapping that takes `UnitDirection -> UnitDirection` directly, rather than `Neighborhood a -> Neighborhood a`. I didn't do that primarily to make it mirror the rest of this answer more closely, but also because it arguably makes for a more honest interface -- rearranging indices in an `Array` is not quite as straightforward as applying an arbitrary function to the indices.)

There are two limitations of this attempt to define another functor:

- We already have a `Functor` instance, as you point out. It wouldn't be sensible to replace just for this use case, and defining a `newtype` for it would be too annoying.
- Even if that wasn't the case, `mapOverNeighborhoods` can't be made into a `Functor` instance, as `fmap` takes arbitrary `a -> b` functions, and changing the type of the neighborhoods is not an option.

These two concerns are addressed by optics libraries such as [*lens*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16) (if you end up using optics for just this one thing in your code base, though, you might prefer [*microlens*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/microlens) for a smaller dependency footprint).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-} -- makeLenses needs this.
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-} -- For the sake of convenience.
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}

-- Record fields on sum types are nasty; these, however, are only here for the
-- sake of automatically generating optics with makeLenses, so it's okay.
data Tree a
    = Empty 
    | Leaf { _value :: a } 
    | Internal { _value :: a, _neighborhood :: Neighborhood a }
    deriving (Eq, Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
makeLenses ''Tree

applyPermutation :: Permutation -> Tree a -> Tree a
applyPermutation perm = over neighborhood applyPermutation'
    where applyPermutation' = ixmap (Xp, Zm) (perm !)
```

`over` (infix spelling: `%~`) is literally an `fmap` which allows choosing the targets. We do that by passing it an appropriate optic (in this case, `neighborhood`, which is a `Traversal` that targets all neighborhoods in a tree -- `over neighborhood` can be read as "map over all neighborhoods"). Note that the fact that we can't change the type of the neighborhood is not a problem (and also, in other circumstances, it would be possible to have type-changing optics).

On a final note, the type of `neighborhoods` is `Traversal' (Tree a) (Neighborhood a)`. If we expand the `Traversal'` type synonym, we get:

```
GHCi> :t neighborhood
neighborhood
  :: Applicative f =>
     (Neighborhood a -> f (Neighborhood a)) -> Tree a -> f (Tree a)
```

While going into the reasons why it is like that would make this answer too long, it is worth noting that this is a lot like the signature of `traverse` for `Tree`...

```
GHCi> :set -XTypeApplications
GHCi> :t traverse @Tree
traverse @Tree
  :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> Tree a -> f (Tree b)
```

... except that it acts on the neighborhoods rather than on the values (cf. the parallel between `fmap` and `mapOverNeighborhoods`). In fact, if you were to adequately implement the `traverse` analogue with that type, you would be able to use it instead of the one automatically generated by `makeLenses`.

Comment: Thanks. You mention very interesting ideas. I've seen *lens* often without knowing what it meant. This is clearly a motivation to learn more about it.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, I coded a small variant based on catamorphisms, exploiting `recursion-schemes`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase, DeriveFunctor, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies, 
    DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable, TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH

import Data.Array
data UnitDir = Xp | Xm | Yp | Ym | Zp | Zm
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded, Ix)

type Neighborhood a = Array UnitDir (Tree a)

data Tree a = Empty | Leaf a | Internal a (Neighborhood a)
    deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)

-- Use TH to automatically define a base functor for Tree,
-- enabling recursion-schemes
makeBaseFunctor ''Tree
```

The wanted mapping function is then:

```
mapOverNeighborhoods :: (Neighborhood a -> Neighborhood a) -> Tree a -> Tree a
mapOverNeighborhoods f = cata $ \case
   EmptyF -> Empty
   LeafF x -> Leaf x
   InternalF x nb -> Internal x (f nb)
```

Roughly, `cata` does all the recursion for us. It provides to its function argument (`\case ...`, above) a value of type `TreeF a (Tree a)` which is essentially the same as a plain `Tree a` except that the very first "layer" uses different constructors, ending with an extra `F`. All such constructors have their inner trees already pre-processed by `cata`: above, we can assume that all the trees inside the `nb` array already had `f` applied recursively. What we need to do is to handle the first "layer", transforming the `F` constructors into the regular ones, and applying `f` to this first "layer" as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well. I'm really impressed by what Haskell can do. It's the third time I dive into this language and I think it will be hard from now on to go back to other languages! Reading about catamorphisms, lens and so on is definitely the next step!